# API Gateway not forwarding path parameters to URI for VPC Link integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

we recently changed our paths such that our APIs now use path parameters. We have some APIs that are running in EC2 containers. Since we made this change, these methods have stopped working. I found that the path parameters aren't getting forwarded to the URIs for the APIs. The image will help things make sense.
How do I get path parameters to work for this scenario? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint uri should set the Host header. You should be able to extract the path from there?

Note: I would have commented this but not enough SO points :(

Comment: are you saying to put the path in the header? I don't quite understand what you mean and thanks.